# Type Error : NoneType is not subscriptable

Tags: python, for-loop, drop

```
for i in Leads.columns:
    if (Leads[i].isnull().sum()/Leads.shape[0]) > 0.40:
        Leads = Leads.drop(i,axis=1,inplace = True)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17092/1952428833.py in <module>
      2 
      3 for i in Leads.columns:
----> 4     if (Leads[i].isnull().sum()/Leads.shape[0]) > 0.40:
      5         Leads = Leads.drop(i,axis=1,inplace = True)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```
for i in Leads.columns:
    if (Leads[i].isnull().sum()/Leads.shape[0]) > 0.40:
        Leads = Leads.drop(i,axis=1,inplace = True)
```

I was expecting the columns having more than 40% missing values to be dropped

Comment: You have used `inplace` so the method returns nothing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inplace` parameter makes the modificaiton on the called object, and returns nothing

Either remove the assignment

```
for i in Leads.columns:
    if (Leads[i].isnull().sum() / Leads.shape[0]) > 0.40:
        Leads.drop(i, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Or remove the `inplace`

```
for i in Leads.columns:
    if (Leads[i].isnull().sum() / Leads.shape[0]) > 0.40:
        Leads = Leads.drop(i, axis=1)
```